# Check backward compatibility of Proto file with new and previous version using generic code

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

If there is a requirement of generic code that test all the proto file in a directory and checks whether currently changed proto file is backward compatible with its immediate previous version.

Is there any framework available in python to do so?